# keep track of beginning and end of linked list

Tags: c

I need to keep track of the beginning and end of a linked list

But i want to use a secondary struct:

```
typedef struct difl{
    Lint start, end;
} dselist;
```

Lint is defined this way:

```
typedef struct slist* Lint;

typedef struct slist{
    int value;
    Lint next;
} Nodo;
```

And this is the function to add an element to the end:

```
void snocs(dselist *l, int x){
    Lint new;
    new = (Lint) calloc(1,sizeof(Nodo));
    if(new==NULL){
        printf("Error in memory allocation\n");
        return;
    }
    new->value = x;
    new->next = NULL;

    if((*l).start==NULL & (*l).end==NULL){
        (*l).start = new;
        (*l).end = new;
    }else{
        ((*l).end)->next = new;
        (*l).end = new;
    }
}
```

And i am calling the function this way:

```
int main(){
    Lint a = NULL;
    Lint b = NULL;

    dselist dl;

    dl.start = a;
    dl.end = b;

    snocs(&dl, 5);
}
```

There aren't compilation errors, just doesn't seem to change anything on my lists.

Comment: How do you know whether anything changes?

Comment: Unrelated, but don't write `(*l).end` but rather `l->end`.

Comment: You're using the bitwise-and operator `&` instead of the logical and `&&`.

Comment: Don't understand the downvote... @MatthewRead i am using the & on purpose.

Comment: "i am using the & on purpose" -- what purpose could that possibly be?

Comment: If you're using a bitwise and on a pointer on purpose you are either amazingly brilliant or don't know what that means. :)

Comment: @DavidHoelzer the bitwise operation isn't made between 2 pointers, but rather between the bool result of the comparison. Do you agree?

Comment: Your code works for me, as it should, despite use of `&` where `&&` is more appropriate.

Comment: Common guys, i'm learning C and sometimes i get stuck on the simplest things, like using printf(); correctly. Don't downvote without clarifying what i've made as a mistake (question structure, bad language, etc)

Comment: @skills, yes, the bitwise operation is on the results of the two `==` comparisons.  The type of those intermediate results depends on which version of C you are using.  `&` is still the wrong operator.

Comment: I downvoted you because contrary to your claim, your code works.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I understand the differences between the operators, i knew it worked by using one, don't ask me why but i didn't see any problem using & instead of &&, but can you clarify on why it's better to use &&?

Comment: `&` is the wrong operator because it is an arithmetic operator, not a logical one.  I can understand being confused about the difference, especially since in this particular case both happen to work, but when you are evaluating a compound condition, use the logical operator.  It is the proper tool for the job.  Moreover, there is a semantic difference even in this case: the logical operator performs short-circuit evaluation, but the arithmetic one does not.

Comment: Since this code is apparently working, it should be closed and deleted as per the off-topic flagging reason "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers".

Comment: @skills Yes it is, but it is still the wrong operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works.

```
struct slist;

typedef struct slist* Lint;

typedef struct slist{
    int value;
    Lint next;
} Nodo;

typedef struct difl{
    Lint start, end;

} dselist;

void snocs(dselist *l, int x){
    Lint new;
    new = (Lint) calloc(1,sizeof(Nodo));
    if(new==NULL){
        printf("Error in memory allocation\n");
        return;
    }
    new->value = x;
    new->next = NULL;

    if((l->start==NULL) && l->end==NULL){
        l->start = new;
        l->end = new;
    }else{
        (l->end)->next = new;
        l->end = new;
    }
}

int main(){
    Lint a = NULL;
    Lint b = NULL;

    dselist dl;

    dl.start = a;
    dl.end = b;

    snocs(&dl, 5);
    printf("%d\n", *dl.start); /* print 5*/

}
```

Comment: thank you for the clarification. Notice that the bitwise operation is made over the result from the comparisons and not by making a bitwise op between the 2 pointers. 

Thank you for pointing things out, i was printing wrongly. Please test the code with only one &, it will work ok.

Comment: I don't doubt that this does work, but it is not a good answer to the question because the original code works, too.

Comment: @JohnSmith good point. Will select as the right answer, would suggest you to remove the first line, because it works with both operators

Comment: changed the first line.